# Applications of module's length

Tags: commutative-algebra, soft-question

I'm studying some theory about module's length and want to know motivation for this definition. I know that it's useful for intersection theory, but i know only one example from intersection theory: $$(C_1\cdot C_2)_P = \ell(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A^2},P}/(f,g))$$ But in this case it's just dimension over field.

Comment: Just using $\dim_k$ doesn't work to measure orders of functions at points when you're not working on a curve. For that you really do need to use the length. See the first few pages of Fulton's *Intersection Theory*.